# Can a user ask a question that can't easily be answered on Google?

Tags: discussion, support

I want to know if a user can ask a question whose solution is hard to find on Google, like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806790/get-all-the-photos-from-pc-and-copy-them-into-usb).

[image: deleted question]

Some questions will never get solved by Google research because they are hard to explain in keywords. This linked question is about help for a starting point and was asked because the OP did not find anything helpful on Google, but once they posted it on this site it got negative votes and, due to this, the OP deleted the question.

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306912/can-we-ask-a-question-that-can-not-easily-we-can-found-on-google) is your previous (now deleted) question. Why did you ask a new question?

Comment: *"Any reference or guide"* is **explicitly off-topic**. Yes, you can ask questions that can't be trivially answered by Googling (indeed, we'd much prefer that people didn't ask questions they could have answered so easily themselves), but not **all** questions.

Comment: That's is offtopic: any question where you ask how to implement an entire feature will always be closed.  And hopefully, that feature is impossible: how would you like it if someone plugged a usb into your computer and it silently copied all files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't ask that question. It is either too broad or asking for an off-site resource.

Instead you could have shown the code that copies the images to an USB drive. Then you could have asked, if you would have found [`autorun.inf`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=autorun.inf), how you can auto start that application when present on an USB drive.

If you don't know where to search, you can always include the search results. Something like *I searched for "execute USB drive" and from that I tried  `start java usb.jar`, but that only works if I double-click the cmd file* or something along those lines. Keep the steps small. *I want to create an app* should be avoided. *In my app I copy files to the USB drive, but that fails with error 0xDEAD, what can be wrong* is a much more precise issue that is answerable in a few paragraphs.

Remember that on Stack Overflow we never want to do the research for you, but we are happy to help you if you tried something/anything you found, show why/what didn't work out, and based on what assumption you went down that route. That info is enough for visitors of your question to either fix your issue or rectify your assumptions and direct you to a better solution.